# Expo notification click to action

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, push-notification, expo

I can't seem to find a solution when I get a push notification and click on it redirects me to a screen, chat, etc. link to push notification.

I would also like to add a square image to the side and could not find an answer.

[image]

The push notifications are sent from a NodeJS server I looked at the docs and search the internet and I did not find anything of interest.

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#managing-notification-categories-interactive-notifications

https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node

Thank you in advance for your answers ❤️

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure about the square image, but in order to handle redirects you can look at this documentation from expo: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/receiving-notifications/.

You can then pass the data you need for your redirect (i.e. notification_type, relevant id etc) via the data property on your message (this will need to be done wherever the message is created, which from your question is from the node api):

```
messages.push({
  to: pushToken,
  body: 'This is a test notification',
  data: { notification_type: 'something', id: 'something_else' },
});
```

It is then up to you to decide how to handle that message based on the extra data you have provided.

For example, taking the code provided in the link above as an example, you could have a handle function as follows:

```
_handleNotification = response => {

    const data = response.notification.request.content;
    if (data.type === "new_message") {
       // navigate to MessageScreen with data.id as param
    } else {
       // do something else based on the type or...
    }
};
```